# Implementing Serial CLI on Arduino

Tags: terminal, arduino, serial-port, command-line-interface, screen

I'm trying to implement a serial cli where you can type and edit a command using a console like screen/minicom. In my testing, I'm using screen to connect to the serial interface. In trying to implement a delete character option, I'm not seeing the results I'm expecting.

I've been reading online on how to use ANSI escape sequences, which I'm finding that some such as `ESC c` to clear screen, and `ESC[?25l` to hide the cursor are working with my tests. But when I try to use `ESC[1D` to move the cursor to the left by 1, or any other cursor escape sequences, it isn't working as I would expect.

I've read through https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html and https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797 for help on how to do this right.

For an example of some test code I'm using:

```
void SendESC(const char *code) {
    Serial.write(27);
    Serial.print(code);
}

void loop() {
    char byteRead = Serial.read();
    if (byteRead==8) {
        if (m_buffer_read!=0) {
            m_buffer_read--;
            m_buffer[m_buffer_read] = '\0';
            SendESC("[1000D");
            SendESC("[0K");
            Serial.print(m_line_indicator);
            Serial.print(m_buffer);
            size_t lineLen = strlen(m_line_indicator)+m_buffer_read;
            char buf[7];
            SendESC("[1000D");
            sprintf(buf, "[%dC", lineLen);
            SendESC(buf);
        }
    }
}
```

In running the above test, it seems like screen does not know the escape sequences are over and it does not pick up on the updated information. I can however confirm with a hex view of the serial data received that the escape sequences are being sent exactly as I expect.

Am I missing something?

Comment: To interact with screen or minterm, you need to know what terminal it trying to emulate, screen emulates a VT100 terminal by default, and there is a complete manual for it, read [this part](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Virtual-Terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I cheated a bit and looked at the hexadecimal output from Linux over serial. Apparently Linux is using `\x08\x1b[K` to tell screen to delete, and also I learned that screen sends the ASCII code 127 instead of 8 for delete. I will continue to look at what Linux uses to finish developing this. Hopefully this helps someone else trying to do the same thing.